# Android JSON parsing pound symbol coming up as?

Tags: java, android

I have a JSON file which contains a pound symbol in it. This json is pulled from a file stored on the phone temporarily. It will come from a server, but for time being I am just storing it on the phone. I convert the JSON file to an input stream and use a method to convert it to a string like this

```
Resources res = getResources();
String sJsonVariables = iStream_to_String(res
                .openRawResource(R.raw.widgvariables));
```

The iStream_to_String method is this

```
public String iStream_to_String(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 4096);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
        return contentOfMyInputStream;
    }
```

I have tried printing out the json using Log.v to test it is printing out okay. Everything prints out fine except for the pound symbol. I have tried several different ways of encoding it like this

```
byte []b = sJsonVariables.getBytes();

        String s1 = new String(b, "UTF-8");
        String s2 = new String(b, "ASCII");
        String s3 = new String(b, "Cp1252");
        String s4 = new String(b, "ISO8859_1");
```

However none of them will print out the pound symbol, it either comes out as a black question mark or some other weird symbol. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how I can get this symbol to print out properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as well with try catch `byte []b = sJsonVariables.getBytes("UTF8");` and the String with `String s3 = new String(b, "Cp1252");`

Comment: Nope, same thing happens unfortunately

Comment: Well the first UTF-8 encoding style with that method returns the black question mark, the others just remove it entirely

Comment: Cheers used that method with Cp1252 encoding and it works fine now

Comment: You should **never** use `getBytes(ENCODING1)` and `new String(ENCODING2)`. It's like saying "give me this word in French, and pretend it's actually English". Completely idiotic, but often suggested by people who have no idea how encodings work.