# Pound symbol parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, non-ascii-characters

I get input text from an external system containing Pound '£' symbol that needs to be parsed and stored as it is in our system. The issue is - it gets converted to junk character like ? mark when run in solaris/unix.

Note - the application runs in windows properly, but in solaris and unix it corrupts the symbol. Our Solaris has jdk1.6.x

I tried with character encoding - UTF-8,UTF-16 and ISO8859_1  but won't help.
Please help.

Sample code with just a text file containing text: THE £1 HOUSES

```
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream in = null; 
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(new File("src//resources//mytext.txt"));
    in = new DataInputStream(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "ISO8859_1"));
    System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : " + is.available());
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hi @Jim Garrison, I have used the following command in unix to generate a hexdump

```
od -x mytext.txt
```

And it is -

```
0000000 5448 4520 a331 2048 4f55 5345 5300
0000015
```

Comment: If it's a single `?`, that would indicate it's an `ISO-8859-1` (or other similar one byte encoding) pound sign trying to be interpreted as `UTF-8`. Make sure you haven't corrupted the file too.

Comment: Pls refer following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133851/android-json-parsing-pound-symbol-coming-up-as/11133911#11133911 seems similar to one you are facing

Comment: If you do not use exactly the same file, it might be encoded differently under Windows and Linux. So the encoding required to read the file might depend on the environment where you run your application.

Comment: @ChristopheWeis and that would be a serious flaw in the file creation process.

Comment: The place to start is to do a hex dump (`xxd` or `hexdump -C`) of the file to determine what code point represents the GB pound sign.  Please do that and [edit] your post to include the output (format as `code`).